# Inconsistent list indent in Ansible/Yaml file

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have an Ansible YAML file formatted like below. Notice the `- name` and `- when` parts.

```
- name: populate package facts
  package_facts:
- name: install auditd
  apt:
    name: auditd
    state: present
  register: apt_status
  until: apt_status is success
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
- name: touch stig.rules
  file:
    path: /etc/audit/rules.d/stig.rules
    state: touch
    mode: '0640'
    modification_time: preserve
    access_time: preserve
# R-238197 UBTU-20-010002
- name: stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
    section: org/gnome/login-screen
    option: banner-message-enable
    value: "{{ ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable_Value }}"
    no_extra_spaces: yes
  notify: dconf_update
  when:
    - ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197_Manage
    - "'gdm3' in packages"
```

I process it and remove some elements then dump to a file using the method below:

```py
def dump(path: str, export: list) -> None:
    yaml: YAML = YAML()
    yaml.default_flow_style = False
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    yaml.width = 4096 # Prevent line breaks
    yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0) # Default values

    with open(path, "w", encoding=ENCODING) as fp:
        yaml.dump(export, fp)
```

With default indentation the result will be like below:

```
- name: populate package facts
  package_facts:
- name: install auditd
  apt:
    name: auditd
    state: present
  register: apt_status
  until: apt_status is success
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
- name: touch stig.rules
  file:
    path: /etc/audit/rules.d/stig.rules
    state: touch
    mode: '0640'
    modification_time: preserve
    access_time: preserve
# R-238197 UBTU-20-010002
- name: stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
    section: org/gnome/login-screen
    option: banner-message-enable
    value: "{{ ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable_Value }}"
    no_extra_spaces: yes
  notify: dconf_update
  when:
  - ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197_Manage
  - "'gdm3' in packages"
```

As you can see, the Ansible file is a list of elements already, starting from offset 0. Then, the list items after `- when` will also use that 0 offset value. How can I preserve the original indentation -offset 0 for `- name` but offset 2 for all others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ruamel.yaml you can only have one indent for all mappings and one for all sequences.

If you want to preserve the inconsistency, you need to indent with 4 and an offset 2 and remove the
extra two spaces that start every line (effectively dedenting the root level sequences):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
YAML = ruamel.yaml.YAML
from pathlib import Path

def dump(path: str, export: list) -> None:
    def strip_first_two(s):
        res = []
        for x in s.splitlines(True):
            xl = x.lstrip()
            # do not dedent full comment lines
            if xl and xl[0] == '#' or not x.startswith('  '):
                res.append(x)
            else:
                res.append(x[2:])
        return ''.join(res)

    yaml: YAML = YAML()
    yaml.default_flow_style = False # default
    yaml.width = 4096 # Prevent line breaks
    yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    yaml.dump(export, Path(path), transform=strip_first_two)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load(Path('input.yaml'))
dump('output.yaml', data)
print(Path('output.yaml').read_text())
```

which gives:

```
- name: populate package facts
  package_facts:
- name: install auditd
  apt:
    name: auditd
    state: present
  register: apt_status
  until: apt_status is success
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
- name: touch stig.rules
  file:
    path: /etc/audit/rules.d/stig.rules
    state: touch
    mode: '0640'
    modification_time: preserve
    access_time: preserve
# R-238197 UBTU-20-010002
- name: stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
    section: org/gnome/login-screen
    option: banner-message-enable
    value: "{{ ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197__etc_gdm3_greeter_dconf_defaults_enable_Value }}"
    no_extra_spaces: yes
  notify: dconf_update
  when:
    - ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238197_Manage
    - "'gdm3' in packages"
```

If you have any end-of-line comments than these will shift two positions to the left.
If you don't have multi-line scalars that have embedded comment markers you can easily handled
that in `strip_first_two` by replacing `' #'` with `'   #'` in each line. If you have both this is not so trivial
and you would have to walk the data structure before dumping and adjust each start column of each EOL comment.

Setting `yaml.default_flow_style = False` is not necessary as that is the default for round-trip dumping (on the other hand explicit
is better than implicit). But you shouldn't set `yaml.preserve_quotes` on the `YAML` instance in your `dump` function as that only
works during loading of a YAML document, so that could actually mislead someone.

I also tend to use `pathlib.Path` instances and let `ruamel.yaml` do the right thing with regards to encoding and opening ('w' vs 'wb').

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. You added more suggestions than what was asked, and I appreciate it, indeed.

Comment: I just need to add another comment. Since I try to minimize the diff,  `yaml.preserve_quotes` is needed. Otherwise, the single quotes can be converted to double quotes while dumping -even when use it on load. So, it is needed both on reading and dumping in my use case.